# how to export gtlf file to godot without crashing?

Tags: animation, blender

I've been working on a project involving around 40 animations in Blender, but I've hit a roadblock when attempting to export the Blender file to Godot. Unfortunately, both the FBX and GLTF formats seem to freeze and crash the moment I click the export button. It's becoming quite a hindrance to my workflow. I've considered the possibility of purchasing a new computer, but before taking such a drastic step, I'm wondering if there are any alternative solutions or troubleshooting steps I can explore to overcome this export issue. How can I go about resolving this problem and successfully export my animations to Godot without encountering these crashes?

also tried exporting one animation at a time and then loading them into the animation player in godot...didn't work, the loaded animations aren't recognized even tho it's the same rig with the same bone names.

Comment: Exporting animations separately and then merging then in Godot is a pain, would not recommend. The only thing that I can think of on Godot side would be to import the .blend file (you need to set the path to blender in editor settings), but since that is based on the GLTF export I won't expect it to solve the problem. I'd say this is something to tackle on Blender side, but I would not know where to start. Addendum: I have added the blender tag. Addendum 2: is blender up to date? Could reinstalling it fix it? Could you get a third party to export them for you?